# ORA-904 When referencing the base table, in a query that includes a nested table and other joins

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've distilled down a problem query to the following example, and I can't find anything on metalink indicating that this is a known bug, or expected behaviour.

The following script is self contained so anyone could reproduce this, I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 enterprise 64-bit running on RHEL, queries being submitted via SQL Developer, the same results occur in SQL Plus.

First : create the nested table type.

```
create type nested_type_test as table of varchar(32);
```

Second : create a table using the type as the nested type.

```
create table nested_table_test (
  uuid          varchar(32)
  , some_values nested_type_test
)
NESTED TABLE some_values STORE AS nested_some_values;
```

Third : create an arbitary table that we will use to create a join statement with.

```
create table join_table (
  uuid  varchar(32)
);
```

Now for some simple SQL statements:

```
select *
from nested_table_test ntt, table(some_Values) sv;

select *
from nested_table_test ntt, table(some_Values) sv
where ntt.uuid = 'X';
```

Both work, I havn't inserted data but for the purposes of this bug / test we do not need to since the issue is a parse issue. Next statement, I add the join to the arbitary table I generated for this purposes.

```
select *
from nested_table_test ntt, table(some_Values) sv
inner join join_table jt on jt.uuid = ntt.uuid;
```

This now produces : `ORA-00904: "NTT"."UUID": invalid identifier` - yet I know that the field exists and could reference it in a where clause. Taking out the `TABLE(some_values)` clause like this,

```
select *
from nested_table_test ntt
inner join join_table jt on jt.uuid = ntt.uuid;
```

and the query works, so I know it is isolated to the existance of the nested table clause within the statement.

If I switch to using a manual join instead of an ANSI join, it then parses and executes again.

```
select *
from nested_table_test ntt, table(some_Values) sv, join_table jt
where jt.uuid = ntt.uuid;
```

Alternatively, and even more hack-ish:

```
select *
from nested_table_test ntt, table(some_Values) sv
inner join join_table jt on 1=1
where jt.uuid = ntt.uuid;
```

Also parses - so it is not the `ntt.uuid` itself that is the problem, but where it occurs within the statement that the parser seems to struggle with.

Known bug, Unknown bug or expected behaviour?

Edit : Using `CROSS JOIN table(some_values) sv` causes a seg fault and a trace file on the server whilst dumping the connection - that one for sure is a bug. It's also why I'm not in pure ANSI join syntax.

Comment: you are using two different way of joining in a single query. Why not use one way the Oracle way.

Comment: Because this is a distilled example to the smallest possible scope of a repeatable test - the real queries are considerably more complex, and ANSI is the preferred syntax. Cross join causes the server to output a seg fault, that itself is definately a bug, no doubt. In the mean time, this would be a suitable way around that, except that it isn't unless I drop back to old style join syntax.

Comment: Ok, so why not all in ANSI?

Comment: I still think that the normal way of joining will make your life a whole lot easier

Comment: You are defining 'normal' as old style commas and (+) operators - I consider ANSI is 'normal', but I work across RDBMs. Neither is relevant to understanding the behaviour.

Comment: @annjawn : started a chat to avoid discussion on comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are mixing up oracle and ANSI join syntax it's the expected behavior. ANSI join takes precedence over `,` comma join(cross join), parsed from left to right, so it means that the `ntt` has not been joined yet when you were trying to reference `ntt.uuid` column and that is why you might get that error. To that end choose one of the join types. For instance:

```
select *
from nested_table_test ntt 
    , table(some_Values) sv
    , join_table jt 
where jt.uuid = ntt.uuid;
```

OR

```
select *
  from nested_table_test ntt
 cross join  table(some_Values) sv
  join join_table jt
    on (jt.uuid = ntt.uuid)
```

Comment: I already tried  - `cross join table(some_values) sv` - it dumps the connection and results in a trace file on the server. Now that itself is definately a bug - but also why that section is not in an ANSI join. Do you have a documentation link that confirms the precedence, and that any `,` joined table is not available to an ANSI join table?

Comment: Using the ANSI cross join along with the ANSI inner join works for me. Database version 11.1.0.7 however.

Comment: Now that I can believe :) I'll go for workaround over downgrade though. I think Nicholas is probably right on precedence, but looking for some documentation to back that up.

Comment: Through some experimentation, I can get the same error on normal tables, by mixing them, but the behaviour is odd - the last table in the comma seperated list is available to the ANSI join, the ones before it are not - I think the precedence is as described, but I can't find any documentation that places this as expected.

Comment: @Andrew In ANSI syntax, join condition can reference only preceding tables that has been join using ANSI syntax.

Comment: @Nicholas : I think you're right and the last table in the comma list would be classed as being part of the ANSI join (since the INNER JOIN has to join between 2 entities) but I can't find any documentation that explicitly states that. Marking as correct for now, but a docs link would be useful.

Comment: Isn't this clear? [`SELECT` in docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm) (the `query_block::` diagram)

Comment: @ypercube - it doesn't indicate any precedence or consequence of mixing in that diagram.